# Hosting a C# WebSocket Server on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tcplistener

I’ve written a WS server from scratch and I’m trying to host it on AWS Elastic Beanstalk service. However, I’ve only figured a way to add it to a web project (that can be hosted on EB) by tacking it on with a thread on startup.cs:

```
Thread thr = new Thread(() =>
            {
                var ws = new WebsocketServer();

            });
            thr.IsBackground = true;
            thr.Start();
```

To my delight and surprise, I was able to successfully test this locally and it works perfectly fine, but when put on EB I am unable to connect to anything (even though I am 99% certain I’m sending requests to the appropriate URL). I’ve tried adding the port I’ve specified but nothing helps.
I’m using a TcpListener initialized like this:

```
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(“127.0.0.1”), 443);
server.Start();
```

And accept clients with a TcpClient like so:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
```

Now based on my experience I assume that the connection is working properly but EB simply does not automatically set it up for public access. Is there any way to do this? Would using the same port as the web app help? (If so, how do I set/see what port it does use?). Since WS is initiated with a HTTP request, is there possibly a way to establish a connection using a Controller method of the format:

```
        [Route("ws")] 
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ConnectWS()
        {
            return await AddClient();
        }
```

I have no Load Balancer set up for the EB environment I'm using.

Lastly, if this is a bad practice or infeasible, is there another AWS service I could use to host the server that’s easy to set up for public connections?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, you need to open up traffic on port 443.  Depending on your Elastic Beanstalk configuration ( *with load balancer? or without load balancer? update your question with this please* )  you are close to getting it to work on AWS.

These high level steps will get you there:

1. Get a cert.  For testing you can install openSSL on your local dev machine and create a self-signed cert.  [AWS has a guide on how to do this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-ssl.html). Note: don't use self-signed certs on your live production system.  When your site goes public, obtain a catchy name and a real cert to front your service.
2. (If no load balancer skip to step 3)  Go to Certification Manager in your AWS console. There is a big blue button, Import Certficiate. Click this. Open the `server.crt` file from step 1 with your favorite text editor and paste the contents in the top box with the label: Certificate body. Then open the `privatekey.cer` file from step 2 with your favorite text editor and paste the contents in the second box with the label: Certificate private key. Click Review and Import and make sure everything is ok
3. If you have a load balancer, follow the steps from this [AWS guide on how to open up 443 on it.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html).  If you don't have a load balancer and it is just a single instance, its a bit more complicated as you have to do it via configuration files.  Follow the steps here:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance.html

Try it out and reply back if you have updates to your question with more config specifics.  I think you are close to working it out and getting it running on AWS.

Comment: Just to clarify, is this to set up https/ws connections? I'm currently just testing a non-secure connection (on, say port 80) and it equally fails. I have went back to non-secure because I was unable to set up that, So I'm definitely using this answer down the line, but first I want to see if *any* connection works.

Comment: Are you deploying via the AWS toolkit inside visual Studio?